# Getting all instances of a 404 error with scrapy

Tags: python, hyperlink, scrapy, duplicates, http-status-code-404

I have Scrapy crawling my site, finding links with a 404 response and returning those to a JSON file. This works really well.

However, I cannot figure out how to get all instances of that bad link since the duplication filter is catching these links and not retrying them.

Since our site has thousands of pages, the sections are managed by multiple teams, I need to be able to create a report of bad links per section rather than finding one and doing a search a replace across the entire site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current crawler:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

# Add Items for exporting to JSON
class DevelopersLinkItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    referer = Field()
    link_text = Field()
    status = Field()
    time = Field()

class DevelopersSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """Subclasses Crawlspider to crawl the given site and parses each link to JSON"""

    # Spider name to be used when calling from the terminal
    name = "developers_prod"

    # Allow only the given host name(s)
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    # Start crawling from this URL
    start_urls = ["https://example.com"]

    # Which status should be reported
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

    # Rules on how to extract links from the DOM, which URLS to deny, and gives a callback if needed
    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(deny=([
        '/android/'])), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

    # Called back to for each requested page and used for parsing the response
    def parse_item(self, response):
        if response.status == 404:
            item = DevelopersLinkItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['link_text'] = response.meta.get('link_text')
            item['status'] = response.status
            item['time'] = self.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

            return item
```

I've tried a few custom dupe filters but ultimately none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, your requests are being filtered by default by the crawlspider. You can use the process_request parameter of the Rule class to set dont_filter=True for each request (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule)